# Reading Foxpro database date field using PHP

Tags: php, oledb, foxpro

I've wrote a PHP script to export a Foxpro database to other formats by using ADODB (http://phplens.com/lens/adodb) library to access Foxpro OLE DB provider.

Everything worked fine except the date fields are mangled and become like these:

```
11/17-/2-00
3/4/-20-08
```

By comparing to actual data I can guess that it is probably in the format of MM/DD/YYYY or m/d/YYYY.

How can I properly export the date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a potential bug or you are missing a setting with the library you are using. I have used the Visual FoxPro OLEDB driver to pull data out of a VFP table with no problem with respect to date formats. VFP stores dates in its own format, but the OLE DB drive will produce those dates in the normal date formats.

Rick Schummer - VFP MVP